# Only get lastest Date time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created this code to pull tickets from our database and also pull the last ticket note date and last ticket user.  It works except for if two people (or more) created a note on the last date (no matter the time difference) it will create multiple lines for each ticket.  How do I fix this?  here is the code:

```
Select distinct t.ticketID,
  t.OpenDate, 
  c.categoryname, 
  s.statusname, 
  p.priorityname, 
  u.firstname, 
  u.lastname, 
  tu.firstname as 'tech_firstname', 
  tu.lastname as 'tech_lastname',
  ltn.maxdate as 'last date',
  ltu.firstname + ' ' + ltu.lastname as 'Last User'

  from ticket t
        left join category c on t.categoryid = c.categoryid
        left join [status] s on t.statusid = s.statusid
        left join [priority] p on t.priorityid = p.priorityid
        left join [user] u on t.userid = u.userid
        left join [user] tu on t.technicianid = tu.userid
        left join ticketnote tn on t.ticketid = tn.ticketid
        inner join (
            Select Max(TicketNoteDate) as MaxDate, max(cast(ticketnotedate as time)) as MaxTime, ticketid, userid
            From ticketNote
            group by ticketid, userid) ltn on tn.ticketid = ltn.ticketid and tn.ticketnotedate = ltn.maxdate and cast(tn.ticketnotedate as time) = ltn.maxtime
        left join [user] ltu on ltn.userid = ltu.userid

  where t.statusid = 1
  and t.LocationID = 1

  order by t.ticketid
```

Comment: You'd better show some sample data.

Comment: google `SQL SERVER ROW_NUMBER() Function`

Comment: Instead of MAX(), use either Row_Number or even TOP 1 in your sub-query.

Comment: Do you want to get the last ticket overall, like amongst ALL tickets, or per user? You have it grouped by ticketid and userid, which surprised me.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in comments, use `row_number` in your subquery where you get the `maximum` value

```
      SELECT row_number() over
            (partition by tiketid, userid 
             order by  TicketNoteDate desc ) as rn, 
             ticketid, 
             userid, 
             ticketnotedate
```

and then `join` with outer query with condition being `rn=1`

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote it getting the max date of all tickets, then finding all tickets with that max date and ordering by time descending and getting the first row and then retrieving extra data (like user) for that entry. I had no way of testing this, but here goes...

```
Select distinct t.ticketID,
  t.OpenDate, 
  c.categoryname, 
  s.statusname, 
  p.priorityname, 
  u.firstname, 
  u.lastname, 
  tu.firstname as 'tech_firstname', 
  tu.lastname as 'tech_lastname',
  ltn.maxdate as 'last date',
  ltu.firstname + ' ' + ltu.lastname as 'Last User'

  from ticket t
        left join category c on t.categoryid = c.categoryid
        left join [status] s on t.statusid = s.statusid
        left join [priority] p on t.priorityid = p.priorityid
        left join [user] u on t.userid = u.userid
        left join [user] tu on t.technicianid = tu.userid       
        inner join (
            select maxdate, maxtime, ticketid, userid, rownum from (
                select maxdate, maxtime, ticketid, userid, row_number() over (order by maxdate desc, maxtime desc) as rownum
                from ticketnote tn,
                (Select Max(TicketNoteDate) as MaxDate
                From ticketNote) mx
                where mx.maxdate = tn.ticketnotedate 
                ) x where x.rownum = 1
        ) ltn
        left join [user] ltu on ltn.userid = ltu.userid

  where t.statusid = 1
  and t.LocationID = 1

  order by t.ticketid
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  For my own information why should I use rownum instead of max?  Is it just convention? or are there technical reasons?